# C# Bluetooth : My deviceInformation is different when I add app.manifest to my project

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth

I created a desktop application using Bluetooth (BLE) and WPF but I have a problem when using app.manifest. For the same device I have different values (DeviceInformation) ​​when I use or not app.manifest. I need to have the app.manifest and I would like to have the same result as without.

My app.manifest :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <!-- Windows 10 -->
            <maxversiontested Id="10.0.18358.0"/>
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
        </application>
        <Capabilities>
            <Capability Name="internetClient" />
            <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
        </Capabilities>
    </compatibility>

</assembly>
```

My csproj :

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <Install>true</Install>
        <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
        <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
        <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
        <Description></Description>
        <Title>Test</Title>
        <Configuration></Configuration>
        <Copyright>Copyright ©  2014-2021</Copyright>
        <UICulture>fr-FR</UICulture>
        <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
        <Guid>02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34627</Guid>
    </PropertyGroup>

    
    </Project>
```

My function bluetooth :

```
        public void Init(string deviceName)
        {
            // Get all Edan paired devices
            DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(SERVICE_UID)).Completed = (asyncFindDeviceInfo, asyncFindDeviceStatus) =>
            {
                if (asyncFindDeviceStatus == AsyncStatus.Completed)
                {
                    Device = asyncFindDeviceInfo.GetResults().Where(d => d.Name == deviceName).FirstOrDefault();

                }
            };
        }
```

Result :

Without app.manifest : DeviceInformation.Name = "EDAN"

With app.manifest : DeviceInformation.Name = "Gatt Service {0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}"